# Check if the files have been uploaded to server with php slim 3

Tags: php, slim

Hi have the following code in slim to save file

I want to make sure the files have been uploaded to the server and only then to return true. or false

how can I do that with Slim or PHP?

Result of file log always null for nonreason and the file are being uploaded

```
public function saveFiles(Array $files, $location) {
    try
    {
        /** @var UploadedFileInterface $file */
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $fileLog = $file->moveTo($location . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file->getFilename());
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
```

Comment: Collect all `$file->moveTo` results and check them.

Comment: result always null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to slim implementaion of this PSR, it always throws exception if something went wrong while file is being uploaded.

I don't know whether you throw another Exception for a reason, but you can process it something like:

```
public function saveFiles(Array $files, $location) {
    $result = true;

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        try {
            $fileLog = $file->moveTo($location . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file->getFilename());
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            // Exception on file uploading happened, but 
            // we still continue loading other files
            $result = false;

            // Or just `return false;` if you don't want
            // to upload other files if exception happened
            // return false;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Of course, this method can be extended to collect exceptions' messages and return them.

Comment: Also if the file has not been completely uploaded ?  , or it just check if file exist

Comment: I don't understand what this question is about.